# How to make a List of Symbols without page number

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, acronyms

I am using the [nomencl](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) package for printing a `List of Symbols` but I do want the `List of Symbols` to appear only without its page number in the `Table of Contents` and there should not be a page number at the `List of Symbols` page itself.

Comment: how about `\pagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: What's the purpose of having something in the table of contents without a clue for finding it in the document?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correct, you do want the nomenclature to appear in the table of contents but without a page number. The nomenclature itself should also not have a page number.

cmhughes's `\pagestyle{empty}` takes us halfway there as it only removes the page number from the page itself. The page has still a page number, it just doesn't show.

You could do it in two ways:

1. Solution 1

   - `intoc` option of `nomencl`,
   - `\pagestyle{empty}`, and
   - `\renewcommand\thepage{}`
2. Solution 2

   - `notintoc` (default) of `nomencl`,
   - `\pagestyle{empty}`, and
   - `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\nomname}{}}`

I'd do this all in a scope (i.e. putting `{}` around it), so that it reverts all settings after the nomenclature (page style/`\thepage` definition).

For a better example it is assumed that the nomenclature appears solely on pages without other content, therefore I added `\clearpage`s before and after the nomenclature

The first solution may be preferred because you don't have to take care at which level the nomenclature should be added to the table of contents.

### Solution 1

```
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
…
{\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand\thepage{}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage}
```

### Solution 2

```
\usepackage[notintoc]{nomencl}
…
{\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\nomname}{}}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage}
```

### Code

The example is taken from the `nomencl` manual.

#### Solution 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Main equations}

\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%

The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.

{\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage}

Text behind the nomenclature with page number
\end{document}
```

#### Solution 2

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notintoc]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Main equations}

\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%

The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.

{\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\nomname}{}}
\printnomenclature
\clearpage}

Text behind the nomenclature with page number
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output of table of contents]

Comment: If we understood the OP correct, now question and answer fit and everything is fine (+1). Otherwise he will fix the question, I hope.