# Omit page number in list of symbos using nomencl

Tags: symbols, lists, page-numbering, acronyms, nomenclature

I'm typesetting a thesis using a custom class based on book class and to meet the university requirements, all pages in frontmatter must not show the page numbers but must be counted, starting at the cover. I was able to change everything, except for the list of symbols and list of abbreviations and acronyms, that were made with the nomencl package.

I tried the solution in this post [How to make a List of Symbols without page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79316/how-to-make-a-list-of-symbols-without-page-number), but using that one, the entry in the toc does not show any page number. I need just to hide the page number of the lists. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: see if the answer in here helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61179/suppress-page-numbers-in-documents-front-matter
else: does the university agree to roman pagenumbering in frontmatter?

Comment: Thanks, @Naphaneal, that one solved the issue. Can you please put it in an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61179/suppress-page-numbers-in-documents-front-matter), the `etoolbox`-package provides `\patchcmd` which can be used to surpress pagenumbering locally in any part of the document, such as indices.

See example in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61179/suppress-page-numbers-in-documents-front-matter) for further information on usage.